Why my unit test cant read file from src/test/resources in unit tests?
I have this method in a utility class in the path src/main/java/packege/Myclass.java:
public static void dummymethod(String file1, String file2) {
     ….
        try (InputStream xsdStream = XMLValidator.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file1)) {
           // do something with file2
           ….
        }
    }….
}

This method reads files from src/main/resources on runtime. However I have now written this unit test and it still attempts to read the files from src/main/resources although I would like it to read the resources from src/test/resources since my utility test is in the path src/test/java/util/mytestclass.class:
public class MyLoginTest {
    @Test
    void testValidfie() {
        String path1 = “file.json”;
        String path2 = “file2.json”;

        dummymethod(path1, path2);

        assertTrue(true);
    }

My unit test cannot find the files located in src/test/resources and still reads files from src/main/resources.
This is the program structure:
my-project
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── package
│   │   │       └── Myclass.java          // Contains dummymethod
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── file.json                  // Resource for production code
│   │       └── file2.json                 // Another resource for production code
│   └── test
│       ├── java
│       │   └── util
│       │       ├── MyLoginTest.java      // Contains testValidFile
│       │       └── OtherTest.java        // Additional tests if needed
│       └── resources
│           ├── file.json                  // Test resource
│           └── file2.json                 // Another test resource

Does anyone understand why this is the case?

You haven't explained what class is where, but I assume that XMLValidator is in your "main" project, so will be using the classloader associated with that. Perhaps you need an overload accepting a class whose classloader should be used to load the resources - then you could pass in MyLoginTest.class, which I'd expect to read from the test resources (assuming you've got that configured...)

The getResourceAsStream method relies on the classpath to locate resources, and the test classpath typically includes both src/main/resources and src/test/resources. However, resources in src/main/resources may take precedence over those in src/test/resources if they have the same name.
Additionally, when you pass a filename like "file.json" without specifying a directory, it tries to find the resource from the default classpath, which could be in src/main/resources.
You should consider creating a method that accepts a classloader as a parameter and call that in your test using the test's classloader and not the XMLValidator's classloader.
public static void dummymethod(String file1, String file2, ClassLoader classLoader){
    try (InputStream xsdStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(file1)) {
        // do something with file2
        // ...
    }
}

public class MyLoginTest {
    @Test
    void testValidfie() {
        String path1 = "file.json";
        String path2 = "file2.json";
        
        // Use the test class loader to load resources from src/test/resources
        dummymethod(path1, path2, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
        
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}

Alternative: Be more explicit with the location of your resrouce
public class MyLoginTest {
    @Test
    void testValidfie() {
        String path1 = "test_resources/file.json"; // Adjust the path as necessary
        String path2 = "test_resources/file2.json";
        
        dummymethod(path1, path2);
        
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}


...resources in src/main/resources may take precedence over those in src/test/resources if they have the same name... - No, they don't. I often use log4j2.xml as resource and can override it for testing.
